# How can I retrieve an XML value based on secondary XML value using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, xml

I'm working on a function to search through XML code and return the max value for a particular tag.

These are my variables:

```
var xmlString= "<root>
    <Item>
        <Name>AAA</Name>
        <ItemNo>22</ItemNo>
    </Item>
    <Item>
        <Name>AAA</Name>
        <ItemNo>10</ItemNo>
    </Item>
    <Item>
        <Name>BBB</Name>
        <ItemNo>122</ItemNo>
    </Item>
    <Item>
        <Name>BBB</Name>
        <ItemNo>99</ItemNo>
    </Item>
</root>";

tagName = 'ItemNo';
nameVal = 'AAA';
```

So far, I'm able to get the max value for ItemNo like so:

```
// parse XML
parser = new DOMParser();
xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(xmlString,"text/xml"); 
// get nodes from XML
var nodes = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName(tagName); 
//array
var arr = [];
// loop through nodes and push values to arr
for (var i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++){
    arr.push(nodes[i].firstChild.data)
}
// get max value from arr
var maxVal = Math.max.apply(null,arr);
alert(maxVal);
```

But, I'm wanting to return the max value for ItemNo where Name = AAA (valName).

Comment: you need to gather the Item tag, and based on the value of each's Name tag, then add the ItemNo tag (or not) to the output you feed to max().

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm trying to achieve, just unsure how. I need to update my question with that clarification. Thanks!.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a node fetching helper makes it simpler:

```
function kid(base, tag){
  return (base.getElementsByTagName(tag)[0]||{textContent:""}).textContent.trim();
}


// parse XML
tagName = 'ItemNo';
nameVal = 'AAA';
parser = new DOMParser();
xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(xmlString,"text/xml"); 

// get nodes from XML
var nodes = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName(tagName); 

var arr = [];
// loop through nodes and push values to arr
for (var i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++){
    if(kid(nodes[i], "Name") == "AAA") arr.push(kid(nodes[i], "ItemNo"));
}

// get max value from arr
var maxVal = Math.max.apply(null,arr);
alert(maxVal);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like the following. You already have to iterate, why not just do the evaluation there.

```
// parse XML
parser = new DOMParser();
xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(xmlString,"text/xml"); 
// get nodes from XML
var nodes = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName(tagName); 

let maxVal = 0;
let tagName = ['AAA'];
// loop through nodes and if correct tag type, compare and set value
for (let i in nodes){
    if (!tagName.includes(nodes[i].Name)) continue;
    if (parseInt(nodes[i].ItemNo) > maxVal) maxVal = nodes[i].ItemNo;
}
alert(maxVal);
```